# how can to use array containing c++ map

Tags: c++

I have difficulty understanding this part of a code? Is it possible to get pictorial/diagram explanation.

```
//test.h
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> mType;
    static const m_Type::value_type data[] = {
        m_Type::value_type("A", "B"),
        m_Type::value_type("C", "D"),
        m_Type::value_type("E", "F")
    };
//test.cc
void test(std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type data)
{
    cout<<data[0].first<<endl;
}
//main.cc
test(data);
```

In main.cc I wanted to call test() to print elements but getting error

```
main.cc: In function 'void test(std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
main.cc:10: error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'data[0]'
```

Comment: You might want to check the prototype of the `test` function and compare it with the definition in `test.cc`. I'll bet it doesn't match, because if it did you would have *another* compiler error from `main.cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the function the following way

```
void test( const std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type data[] )
{
    cout<<data[0].first<<endl;
}
```

because originally data is defined as an array that you are going to pass to the function. Otherwise you may not use the subscript operator.

Also you need to use qualifier `const` for the parameter because array data also is defined as a constant array.

As for this type

```
m_Type::value_type
```

then it is equivalent to `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` So this declaration

```
static const m_Type::value_type data[] = { /*...*/ };
```

is equivalent to

```
static const std::pair<const std::string, std::string> data[] = { /*...*/ };
```

Comment: add the `const` to the function signature too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How can I calculate the size of data?  sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]) gives me zero since data = 8 and data[0]= 16.

Comment: @dochoex You need to add one more parameter that will specify the size of the array because the array passed by value to the function is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Or you could define a template function that defines the parameter as a refernce to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass to test a `value_type` not the whole map.
A value_type corresponds to a pair(key, value) and is define like so in stdlib : `typedef pair<const Key, Type> value_type;`

therefore this `data[0]`makes no sense. Should be `data.first`